# How to install Wine 1.9 on Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: wine

I am not really a fan of stable branches and have moved to Wine 1.7 as soon as it spawned from Wine 1.6 and have been using it for years without a problem.

So, now, as Wine 1.8 stable has been released and Wine 1.9 created as a successor to Wine 1.7 I would really like to install it (Wine 1.9).

However I can't find any PPA with it. The ["Ubuntu Wine Team" PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) seems to provide some related packages like "wine-gecko1.9" but not wine1.9 itself. The ["Official Wine builds" PPA](https://launchpad.net/~wine/+archive/ubuntu/wine-builds/) provides wine-devel packages but I don't really understand what are they  meant for as installing them does not actually install wine.

So how do I install Wine 1.9?

PS: Of course I can always build it from sources and install it to /opt but I'd prefer a more tidy PPA way.

Comment: @Daniel are you serious? Have you even read the question? I know how to install wine 1.6, 1.7 and even 1.8.

Comment: Theoretically wine1.9 would be released through the same medium as wine1.8.  Have you tried `apt-get install wine1.9`?

Comment: @Daniel of course I have, and I have hand-looked into the repository: as I have said I have found some related packages like wine-gecko1.9 there suggesting that wine1.9 was going to follow but weeks have passed and wine1.9 is still not there.

Comment: Stable, Development and Staging can now be found in the same How to install and configure Wine question since Wine's 1.8.0 release.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you mention that unstable wine is okay for you, [you can use PPA](https://github.com/wine-compholio/wine-staging/wiki/Installation#-ubuntulinux-mint) of [wine-staging](http://www.wine-staging.com/). I am using it right now, and I have the 1.9 version. Note however, that the purpose of wine-staging is testing experimental features, which aren't yet merged with the main branch.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends wine-staging
sudo apt-get install winehq-staging
```

Comment: Miraculously this works although no package with such a name is listed at https://launchpad.net/~wine/+archive/ubuntu/wine-builds/+packages and the list is much more humble than that of  https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages And it also needs just a couple of seconds to install (totally incomparable with previous versions) and works perfectly. This makes me wonder why were previous versions so big...

Comment: @Ivan, the strict equivalent of the 1.7 series in 1.9 series is wine-devel. You should change `staging` to `devel` in above command lines if this is what you want. [Staging](https://www.wine-staging.com/) adds experimental features on top of the 'in dev' features. That is what Hi-Angel warn about, but it was not clear enough for me and I had to double check to get it.

Answer (score 3):

hmm i dont suggest using a ppa, i prefer another way to get the newest wine versions and manage them and it is called [playonlinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/)

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

then go to **Tools->Manage wine versions** and choose your wine version to install, it is regularly updated and lets you use many versions of wine together and install libraries easy (easier than winetricks IMHO).

It is very easy to delete old wine versions and/or virtual drives and it will always have the latest wine available!

If you want to run an app through playonlinux: you have to create a new virtual drive, open a Command Prompt and browse to the directory to run the .exe

Comment: I love pure Wine (and want 100% hand control over it because I am a very-very experienced "power user" of Windows having had been tweaking it since version 3.11) and generally dislike introducing unnecessary extra entities (remember William of Ockham) generally. But thank you for sharing your experience anyway.

Comment: Playonlinux should not be recommended "instead" of wine, at least for "advanced users". I think that actual benefits are not in playonlinux, but in multiple versions of wine installed at once. This is possible without playonlinux (probably with building from sources?). Additionally, playonlinux is really bad designed interface.

Comment: Yes, my answer was more of a general one. Although i recognize that playonlinux may not serve "advanced users" that well, there might be less experienced ones viewing this question and playonlinux IS easier than building from sources or ppas/winetricks! Many apps may work better on older wine versions as well! Also I dont agree with you on the interface!

Comment: What is the issue with using a PPA? I tried the playonlinux and seems pretty interesting but way too hands off and bloated for my needs. The PPA approach posted by @Hi-Angel suits my needs perfectly.